# Equations for a perfect cylinder intersecting a thin plate with a circular cutout

Tags: geometry

Given a perfect cylinder of diameter D standing vertically and of an arbitrary length, and a thin flat plate with a circular cutout which is a slightly larger diameter than D, and they are intersecting such that the plate is resting on a non-horizontal angle as constrained by the cylinder walls, is there a standard solution for determining the resting angle of the plate?

As an example the cylinder is 3" in diameter and 6" tall. The square plate is 1/4" thick, with a circular cutout of 3.25" diameter. The plate can be slipped over the cylinder and made to rest at a specific angle which is constrained by two points within the edges of the 3.25" circular cutout resting against the diametrically opposed walls of the cylinder. The plate will rest at a small angle off of horizontal in this situation (constrained by friction at the two points of contact). I want to calculate the angle of the plate to the horizontal. In this example it would be something like 5 or 10 degrees.

Before diving into a full analysis of this problem on my own, I am asking if there is a standard example of this configuration of a cylinder and a plate, or perhaps a cylinder and a plane (as an example for a very thin plate) that a member can point me to?

Most examples I have found are for a plane intersecting a cylinder at an arbitrary angle - similar but different as the oversize hole is determining the angle in my problem.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I believe this is a question suitable for the Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ds3MrMUz3Z0) about the intersection of a cylinder and a plane.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand the question, but I would expect an angle `ArcCos[dcyl/dcircle]`

Answer (score 2):

This problem is simpler if you project it to 2D (let the cylinder be a rectangle, the plate be a line).

Unfortunately, MMA doesn't do projection of 3D regions to 2D regions.  It also isn't well developed enough to work out the full 3D intersection analytically (it is an ellipse; MMA can only approximate it), nor the 2D region intersection for arbitrary parameter values (though it recognizes that it must be a line).

Your problem involves a rectangle with sides at $\pm D/2$ and a line intersecting the rectangle at $(\pm D/2,\pm\tan\theta)$.  The distance between these points is given by

```
Norm[{D/2,Tan@θ}-{-D/2,-Tan@θ}]
```

Now you assert that this equals $3+\frac14$".  So:

```
Solve[Norm[{3/2,Tan@θ}-{-3/2,-Tan@θ}]==3+1/4,θ]
```

to get $\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)\approx32^\circ$.  Here's some simple graphics code to see that that makes sense

```
Graphics@{FaceForm[], EdgeForm@Black, Rectangle[{-3/2, -1}, {3/2, 1}],
  Line@{{-3/2, -Tan@ArcTan[5/8]}, {3/2, Tan@ArcTan[5/8]}}}
```

[image: 2d]

This assumes an infinitely thin plate.  You actually want the formula for the distance *from bottom left chamfer to top right chamfer* in terms of $\theta$, and then solve for $\theta$.  See if you can work it out.

---

Look at how terribly MMA performs at approximating the mesh!

[image: mesh]

Here's the code for that

```
Manipulate[
Graphics3D@{MeshPrimitives[
DiscretizeRegion@
 RegionDifference[
  TransformedRegion[
   Cuboid[{-D, -D, h/2 - platethickness}, {D, D, 
     h/2 + platethickness}], 
   RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, h/2}]], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, D/2]], 2], Opacity@.3, 
Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, D/2]}, {{D, 3}, 0, 10}, {{h, 6}, 
0, 10}, {{platethickness, 1/4}, 0, 
1}, {{\[Theta], RandomReal@{0, \[Pi]/2}}, 0, \[Pi]/2}]
```

Comment: Adam, I don't know what "MMA" is. However, your insight to project the problem to 2D gives me a good handle on how to go about solving the the problem quantitatively with the tools I do know. Thanks for all of the work you put into this, it is much appreciated and has set me on the right course of action.

Comment: @Adam, see my answer for a better visualization

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment, here is a better way to do the visualization:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ToElementMesh[
    RegionDifference[
     TransformedRegion[
      Cuboid[{-diam, -diam, h/2 - platethickness}, {diam, diam, 
        h/2 + platethickness}], 
      RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, h/2}]], 
     Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, diam/2]]]["Wireframe"],
  Graphics3D@{Opacity@.3, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, diam/2]}
  ], {{diam, 3}, 0, 10}, {{h, 6}, 0, 10}, {{platethickness, 1/4}, 0, 
  1}, {{\[Theta], RandomReal@{0, \[Pi]/2}}, 0, \[Pi]/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I've never played with the FEM package -- time to start!

Comment: @Adam, absolutely! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

An analytic solution is not difficult. With radius of cylinder and circle we may get the angle of the plane by:

```
rcyl = 1;
rcirc = 1.2;
phi = ArcCos[rcyl/rcirc];
h = Sin[phi];
```

We can now define an ellipse with half-axes rcyl and rcirc. As an ellipse is a 2D object we will use the 3D object "Ellipsoide" with one of the 3 half-axes verry small. And we also define the circle:

```
ell = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {rcirc, rcyl, 0.0001}];
cir = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {rcirc, rcirc, 0.0001}];
```

Now we assemble our plot:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
  InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, -h}, {0, 1, 0}}], Opacity[0.5], 
  Rotate[ell, phi, {0, 1, 0}], Rotate[cir, phi, {0, 1, 0}], 
  Opacity[0.3], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, rzyl]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, 1.2 {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `HalfSpace` and `Region` to get the result.

```
normal = {1, 1, 4};
reg = RegionIntersection[HalfSpace[normal, {0, 0, .2}], 
   HalfSpace[-normal, {0, 0, -.2}], 
   ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {x, y, z}]];
Show[Region[Style[reg, Directive[Opacity[.8], Cyan]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, -3}}, 1]}]]
```

[image]